# Lua garbage collection: Will reassigned userdata have its __gc meta event triggered?

Tags: c, api, memory, lua, garbage-collection

When a userdata value is reassigned, i.e.

```
a = lib.new()
a = b
```

Where `a`, `b`, and the result of `lib.new()` are all userdata with a defined `__gc` meta-event, will the garbage collector be called for both values of a (i.e. the return value of `lib.new()` AND the value of `b`)? This appears to be the case here for general Lua objects: [Garbage Collection Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GarbageCollectionTutorial).

Secondly, if `a` is assigned to the value of `b` (`a=b`), will the garbage collector be called twice on the userdata value? (Is the userdata copied or referenced?)

However it is unclear whether this applies to userdata with metatables. For my particular application, I would expect to be receiving seg faults if it is the case for userdata meta-events.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding the difference between "variables" and "values" in Lua. A "variable" is just a holder of some value. A "value" is the actual data.

This is different from C, where a variable *is an object*. In Lua, variables are just named holders for objects.

It is wrong to say that `a` is "userdata with a defined __gc meta-event." The *value held by `a`* does. There's a difference.

The value of tables/userdata/functions are references to the table/userdata/function. Therefore assigning the contents of one variable to another will just transfer the reference.

The garbage collection metamethod will happen exactly when the Lua reference manual says it will: when (or after) the object is garbage collected. And that only happens if it is impossible for your code to access that object anymore, when you cannot access references to it.

If you have a reference in `a`, then you have access to it. So no garbage collection will happen.

Comment: Ok, so one garbage collection method called per userdata created on the C side. Thanks.